# How can I combine two Where/And clauses against the same subquery?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm fine tuning a stored procedure and each subquery I have acts (or at least appears to act) as a mini multiplier. I've tried a few different ways but now I'm not so sure it's as easy as I thought it should be. I keep getting invalid relational operators. If this should be easy feel free to tell me to just keep trying.

I'd like to combine the following two comparisons but I can not find the correct syntax. I'll list what I've tried so far after. Thanks in advance

```
WHERE T.Column_Name = (...Subquery)
AND   S.Column_Name = (...Subquery) --same subquery as above
```

What I've tried so far are variants along this line

```
WHERE (T.Column_Name AND S.Column_Name) = (...Subquery)
WHERE (T.Column_Name, S.Column_Name) ...
WHERE (T.Column_Name AND S.Column_Name = (...Subquery))
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your query a scalar subquery, i.e. does it return only one column of only one row? Your first code piece looks OK, so I assume that the subquery might not be scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE T.Column_Name = (...Subquery) AND T.Column_Name = S.Column_Name
```

Comment: Some quick testing shows it is improving performance by about 1 to 2 seconds. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If the columns from table T and S should be equal to the same subquery result, then they are probably the columns of the join condition. Therefore you could try something like:

```
WHERE  t.column_name = s.column_name
   AND t.column_name = (subquery)
```

Comment: Ah, I was slow to type... :-)

Comment: Thanks you both for the quick reply's it certainly working. I'm testing preformance to see how much difference it makes.